# How to disable Settings & Google Play in a restricted profile?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, restricted-profiles

Using the new 4.3 restricted profile feature I'm able to remove most apps from a restricted profile.

How can I remove the remaining icons (Google Play & Settings) from the App Drawer and the Quick Settings menu? This would be ideal for a complete kiosk mode.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the Play Store icon is still available, it doesn't seem to work on a restricted profile - pressing it on my Nexus 7 results in:

> You don't have permission to use Google Play Store.

Note that Google Play Store doesn't even appear in the list of apps you can enable.

The Settings app is still there, as it allows the user to force stop running apps, etc.

Comment: Better than nothing, I guess.